# STL containers fails to add a structure defined inside a function

Tags: c++

I have enanoutered a problem with a code similar to this

```
void aFuncion()
{
    struct entry
    {
        std::string field1;
        int         field2;
        int         field3;

        entry(const entry& ent)
        { 
            // copy constructor code 
        }

        entry()
        { 
            // default constructor code 
        }

        entry(std::string s, int a, int b)
        { 
            field1 = s;
            field2 = a;
            field3 = b;
        }

    }; //end of structure definition 

    std::vector<entry> vec;
    entry en("a string", 1, 2);

    vec.push_back(en);  // vec has garbage in index 0
}
```

after pushing the entry into the vector the debuggers shows only garbage in the vector first entry.

the problem resolved once we took the structure definition  out of the function.
**why did the problem occur how did getting the definition into  out of the function resolved it ?**

(we are working with VS 2008  on XP 32 bit )

Comment: The index of the entry would be 0, not 1.

Comment: @Neil Butterwort: you are right  of course, I've corrected the remark

Comment: std::vector doesn't have a push() function. You probably mean push_back(). Also please remove the entry:: before you ctors.

Comment: By posting compilable code, you will allow others to test it more easily and you may get more answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current C++ standard does not allow the template arguments to be locally defined types. This is remedied in the upcoming version of the standard.

14.3.1/2:

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

Comment: @avakar: a similar example compiled in our application, so VS, at least in theory,  supports this.  I was asking why it didn't work  as expected.

Comment: Yes, VS2008 supports this as an extension (as does gcc, I believe). Apparently, the debugger does not handle this correctly and you can't really blame it.

Comment: A nice illustration of the general uselessness of language extensions!